# How to retrieve SharedPreferences string?

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences

While working on an android app, I discovered, that I would have to use SharedPreferences to store login data (url, port, name), but since I am new to this, I am not sure, how to access the data for MQTT to use those inputs and login.

in tab3_fragment.java, the SharedPreferences get set this way:

```
    public void saveData(){
        SharedPreferences userDetails = (SharedPreferences) getContext().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userDetails.edit();

        editor.putString(url, input_url.getText().toString());
        editor.putString(port, input_port.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Einstellungen gespeichert", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void loadData(){
        SharedPreferences userDetails = getContext().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        text_url = userDetails.getString(url, " ");
        text_port = userDetails.getString(port, " ");
    }
```

This is how I try to access the SharedPreferences:

```
public MqttHelper(Context context){
        SharedPreferences userDetails = getContext().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        final String url = userDetails.getString(tab3_fragment.url, " ");
        final String port = userDetails.getString(tab3_fragment.port, " ");

        String strArray2[] = {url, port};
        String serverUri = TextUtils.join(":", strArray2);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), serverUri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

When running the above code from within another fragments onCreateView, it runs fine, but when I add the code to the MqttHelper.java, so that it can load the settings, it returns error

```
cannot resolve method `getContext()`.
```

How can I make the MqttHelper access the SharedPreferences?

Comment: getActivity().getContext() ?

Comment: Have you tried passing the _context_ to MqttHelper.java and using context.getSharedPreferences(...)?

Comment: err hold on, yes `public MqttHelper(Context context)` the context *is* passed in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running the above code from within another fragments onCreateView, it runs fine, but when I add the code to the MqttHelper.java, so that it can load the settings, it returns error

> cannot resolve method `getContext()`.

As I can see in your code you are passing the `context` already by parameter, so I don't see any need to use `getContext()` there, you can easy use `context`

Bad

```
public MqttHelper(Context context){
        SharedPreferences userDetails = getContext().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Good

```
public MqttHelper(Context context){
        SharedPreferences userDetails = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Also I'm seeing that you are displaying a `Toast` using `getActivity()` you can use also `getActivity()` to get the `context` as an alternative.